# Set a Variable inside a conditional

Tags: templating, matrix, conditional, variable, logic

I'm building my first Craft site and need to set a variable if a field has an image and then use that variable elsewhere in the template.

The field is part of a matrix and will repeat.

What I have so far is:

```
{# extra image #}
{% set asset = block.extraImage.first() %}
{# set variable empty so it's avialble outside of conditional #}
{% set float = "" %}

{% if asset %}
    <img src="{{ asset.url }}" alt="" class="img-responsive pull-right" />

    {% set float = yes %}           
{% endif %}

<div class="{{ float }}"> more code here </div>
```

The above code doesn't give me any template errors. But it also doesn't output the class as expected.

The full template code can be viewed [here](http://pastie.org/10912043).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to your `float` variable using another variable at the moment that isn't defined. I expect you mean to set `float` to the string value "yes" like so:

`{% set float = "yes" %}`

You could also use a conditional around your `class` declaration so you don't end up with empty classes and it'd also remove the need to define `float` as an empty value.

```
<div{% if float is defined %} class="{{ float }}"{% endif %}> more code here </div>
```